# ROS_NXT Advanced Capabilites?

Tags: nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ROS for the NXT have the capability to do sophisticated statistical calculations such as matrix multiplication and inversion? I'm looking at using it to do some Qlearning algorithms.

EDIT: Are the packages created in ROS not stored on the NXT then? Does your computer need to constantly be connected via bluetooth or USB in order to relay the package info to the brick?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37258/ros_nxt-advanced-capabilites?/) by [Nezteb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2691/nezteb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: as the ROS nodes for nxt don't run on your brick, you are free to use any code / library you want (as long as you can run it on your laptop/pc).

---

Longer answer: The `nxt_ros` package is 'nothing more' than a wrapper around the [nxt_python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nxt-python/1.2.0) Python library. This enables bidirectional communication between ROS and the NXT brick.

As the rest of your ROS nodes "don't care" where their data is coming from or going to, you are free to use any other nodes, as long as their messages are compatible.

This is actually one of the fundamental tenets of component based development: keep implementation specific details 'locked up' inside your components, while using suitable connectors to exchange the proper messages. Ideally, no knowledge about you using the NXT as an actuation platform is ever present in any of your nodes, apart from the `nxt_ros` package (cum suis).

---

Answer to the edit: yes, your computer/laptop will need to be running all the time. As I wrote, the `nxt_ros` package is just a wrapper around a library, facilitating communication between your computer and the brick over usb/bluetooth.

According to [this](http://mindstormsnxt.blogspot.nl/2006/08/whats-inside-nxt-brick.html) page, the brick has a 48MHz ARM7 with 64KB ram. While perhaps [rosserial_arduino](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino) could be adapted to run on it, the brick is in no way powerful enough to run a full blown ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-06-25**:
Exploiting this decoupledness: you could do all your ML in [Matlab](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge) or perhaps a DSL, provided it can be integrated with ROS.